# UnboundLocalError passing list from function to function. Global is declared

Tags: python

```
global GearsList;GearsList=[]
if len(DuplicateList)>0:
 for i in DuplicateList:
  GearsList.append(i)
  for j in UniqueList:
   GearsList.append(j)
  CheckGaps(); GearsList=[]
else:
 GearsList=UniqueList
 file=open('GearsList.csv','w')
 for z in GearsList:
  print>>file,z
 file.close()
 CheckGaps()

def CheckGaps():
 GearsList.sort(key=lambda x:x[1]); list1=[]; base=''
```

The first block is part of a function which passes successfully to CheckGaps.

However, I receive:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'GearsList' referenced before assignment
```

I'm confused as I declare “global GearsList” and GearsList.csv is:

```
(7, 2.8238952201055705, 8, 2.563397837907839, 1.1016219091494361)
(7, 1.0953215668837057, 8, 1.256834873031462, 0.8714920236433373)
```

As an experiment, I wrote the following which works without error.

```
def CheckRatios():
 global GearsList;GearsList=[]
 DuplicateList=[]; UniqueList=[]
 if len(DuplicateList)>0:
  for i in DuplicateList:
   GearsList.append(i)
   for j in UniqueList:
    GearsList.append(j)
   CheckGaps(); GearsList=[]
 else:
  GearsList.append((7, 2.8238952201055705, 8, 2.563397837907839, 1.1016219091494361))
  GearsList.append((7, 1.0953215668837057, 8, 1.256834873031462, 0.8714920236433373))
  file=open('GearsList.csv','w')
  for z in GearsList:
   print>>file,z
  file.close()
  CheckGaps()

def CheckGaps():
 GearsList.sort(key=lambda x:x[1]); list1=[]; base=''
 for i in GearsList:
  print i
 print "   It worked."

CheckRatios()
```

I must be missing something obvious.  What is wrong?

Comment: It is impossible to answer because you have not provided enough context regarding your problem. You should tell us what module and package this function or method is that is trying to call CheckGaps() is in, what is the function, module and package named, and show us the exact stack trace.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I wasn't the clearest.  Regardless, as an experiment, I substituted "bob" for GearsList and it works.  I still don't see the problem with the GearsList name but should be able to figure it out.